# How to run c# code on process startup?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, process

I can write code that runs on a Windows Forms application startup, on Console application's startup or on ASP.NET MVC's startup (Global.asax).

But now I need to write a code to run on startup on any .NET's process/application. I need this because I'm writing a library to be used in different application templates, including Windows Forms, Windows Services, Console applications and in Web projects. I want some configuration to happen automatically when process runs.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: If your library have a static constructor, it will be called on the first usage of your library

Comment: @Martheen, that's correct. But OP asks to do initial configuration automatically, not on a special trigger.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati Not sure the difference between 'automatic' and 'special when called' here. The configuration is only directly used by OP's library anyway. At least that what I do when dealing with log4net configuration on a wrapper library

Comment: Look into DLL Injection.